# How to delete multiple rows in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I made a code for delete the selected row, you can see here:

```
var grid = Players_DataGrid;
var mygrid = Players_DataGrid;

if (grid.SelectedIndex >= 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= grid.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
    {
        mygrid.Items.Remove(grid.SelectedItems[i]);
    };
}

grid = mygrid;
```

But there's a problem. If the user select multiple with `ctrl` combination rows the program crash displaying this exception:

> Argument out of range exception

on `mygrid.Items.Remove(grid.SelectedItems[i]);`

Is my code wrong? Isn't the best way to delete values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you delete an item from the list you are iterating through.
Let's say your list has 10 items so you have an for loop from 0 to 9. If you delete 2 Items you still will iterate to 9 and the list has only 8 items so you get an:

> Argument out of range exception

you can solve this by iterating backwards

```
for (int i = grid.SelectedItems.Count -1; i >= 0; i--)
```

**Edit:** 
the removed item will be removed from `grid.SelectedItems` too.